# setting cookie with domain

Tags: http, cookies

This is pretty much a basic question since I got a bit confused

When we set a cookie with domain `.mydomain.com` refers to use the same cookie over subdomains, what if I do `.test.mydomain.com` does it mean urls like `helloworld.test.mydomain.com` will be able to re-use the cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's how it works. There's no special detection of what level the 'subdomains' are, everything is really a subdomain to the TLD at the least. What if you had a `.co.uk` address?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an intersting article about sharing cookies across subdomains

[15Seconds](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/971108.htm)